# iPod Click Wheel (4G Classic) crashes in the manner of refusing to wake up and I can't seem to figure out why

Tags: itunes, audio, sleep-wake, ipod

I've had this iPod since 2009 and it's been running a 32GB CF card via adapter.  For seven years I've had no problems with it until I wanted to rebuild my library from scratch.  All the files I've had before on it work just fine but if I want to add new tracks there's a high possibility the iPod will only play so many tracks before refusing to wake up when it goes to sleep.  There aren't any tracks the iPod refuses to play so I can't find any specific track that's tripping something in the iPod's memory causing it to fault *consistently*.  All tracks are 128Kbps AAC with VBR.

Things I've tried:
1.  A different motherboard, CF card and adapter.  The issue still persists.  I've not used a standard hard disk.
2.  I've replaced the battery.
3.  Converted all the new tracks to WAV and converted them to AAC to shed ID3 tags and possibly errors with the MP3 codec within iTunes (i.e. some tracks play garbled in iTunes but are completely fine in other players).

I'm just curious if anyone else has stumbled upon this before.